# Can`t send email to client from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I made a test page which has a text box for email address, a button to submit, and an error label.

Here is the C# code I have seen here in the forum:

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("danielohayon2014@gmail.com", (string)txtEmail.Text);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
    mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
    mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
    client.Send(mail);

    lblError.Text = "Message sent!";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

The full error it shows to me is:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.google.com' at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at email.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\WebDev\Test\email.aspx.cs:line 28

But it is not working for me I don`t know what to do help me!

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Is it giving an error message?

Comment: what error do you get? you're going to have to tell us more than "it is not working for me"

Comment: sorry, I have added the full error to the  question body

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the credentials of all Smtp Clients in the web.config by adding this

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="no-reply@yourdomain.com">
                <network host="smtp.host.net" userName="yourUsername" password="yourPassword" port="587" enableSsl="true" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Then your code to send the email becomes simpler

```
try
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("MyEmail@gmail.com", (string)txtEmail.Text);
        mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
        mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
        client.Send(mail);
    }

    lblError.Text = "Message sent!";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your hostname and port are incorrect - gmail uses `smtp.gmail.com` not `smtp.google.com` and the port is 587 not 25.

Your code also does not provide any network credentials. You have correctly set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false, but you need to provide the new NetworkCredentials as well.

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");
```

You also need to enable SSL:

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: it shows me error on `NetworkCredential` (I can`t define an object from this class) should I import a special class?

Comment: @D4NieLDev added a namespace reference.

Comment: Now I have this error:
**System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.**

Comment: You helped me, but @JLevett answered the best thank you!